# If Max for a column then select the name in the A Column that corresponds to the MAX

Tags: excel

[image]

I tried MAXIFS but I don't think I understand how to do it correctly.

=MAXIFS(B5:B9,A5:A9,"F")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use INDEX

```
=INDEX($A$5:$A$9,MATCH(MAX(B$5:B$9),B$5:B$9,0))
```